# WPF access to control template

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to accesso to my Expander object programmatically:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GridData" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}"> 
                                <Expander x:Name="exp" Background="#dedede" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Expander_MouseDown" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="#d0d0d0" Padding="2,0,1,0" Style="{StaticResource StatusGroupExpander}" >
```

Ay hints?

Comment: From where do you need a reference to the `Expander` and when and why?

Comment: I need to access from code behind because I have to add stackpanels and column programmatically to expander

Comment: And what about the when?

Comment: Basically when I init the page, I got a list of columns and I need to put into my expander

Comment: *The* expander? There is no *the* since it's a in a template that is eventually applied to an element in the `DataGrid`. So which expander do you mean? All of them?

Comment: If you see the code you will notice that I omit the content of expander. Basically I would add programmatically a StackPanel with all my required columns (I can't do in XAML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Expander` in the template is eventually applied to a `GroupItem`.

You could handle the `Loaded` event to access each created `Expander` in the code-behind:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Expander expander = (Expander)sender;
    //...
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}"> 
    <Expander x:Name="exp" Loaded="OnLoaded" .... />
    ...
```

Comment: Brilliant! that's a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

You can get the template and find the Expander object by name.

```
var gridTemplate = GridData.Template;
var expander= (Expander)gridTemplate.FindName("exp", GridData);
```

*[The above code is not tested]*